# Looking for a sci fi short story involving vivisection

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story involving a scientist who performs vivisection on apes. I believe it was written in first person. The horror aspect starts coming in when the voices of his coworkers and friends start to distort into a bizarre shriek. He discovers that he has been under the control of aliens (or other dimensional beings) under the veil of the world populous,
And having him perform the vivisection on other humans.

I read this book almost twenty years ago in elementary school. It was on the librarians desk in a basket with dozens of other short stories. It blew my mind and nobody else wanted to hear about it. It put this thought in my head of "who around me is who they say they are". It was also one of my earlier thoughts of what is REALLY going on in the world around me. Even then I was amazed I found such a dark book just tucked away in the mix.

Comment: There exist a full novel Le titan de l'espace, written by Yves Dermeze. In it an interstellar creature of force (who doesn't have a body) kills the crew of space ship and takes over their bodies (eats their life force and replaces it with motor force). He takes over the captain and sees through his eyes and orders the other crewmembers to come to his cabin. Then does a vivisection of the other crewmember. It turns out there is a creature of force (only much smaller) is already living on Earth and feeding on humans.

Comment: It's not quite the story I'm looking for, but sounds interesting. If I can find it in english I'll grab it.  Thanks Jo.